# Custom Rx operator for throttling only when there's a been a recent value

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm trying to create an Rx operator that seems pretty useful, but I've suprisingly not found any questions on Stackoverflow that match precisely. I'd like to create a variation on `Throttle` that lets values through immediately if there's been a period of inactivity. My imagined use case is something like this:

I have a dropdown that kicks off a web request when the value is changed. If the user holds down the arrow key and cycles rapidly through the values, I don't want to kick off a request for each value. But if I throttle the stream then the user has to wait out the throttle duration every time they just select a value from the dropdown in the normal manner.

So whereas a normal `Throttle` looks like this:
[image: Normal Throttle():]

I want to create `ThrottleSubsequent` that look like this:
[image: ThrottleSubsequent():]

Note that marbles 1, 2, and 6 are passed through without delay because they each follow a period of inactivity.

My attempt at this looks like the following:

```cs
public static IObservable<TSource> ThrottleSubsequent<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, TimeSpan dueTime, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    // Create a timer that resets with each new source value
    var cooldownTimer = source
        .Select(x => Observable.Interval(dueTime, scheduler)) // Each source value becomes a new timer
        .Switch(); // Switch to the most recent timer

    var cooldownWindow = source.Window(() => cooldownTimer);

    // Pass along the first value of each cooldown window immediately
    var firstAfterCooldown = cooldownWindow.SelectMany(o => o.Take(1));

    // Throttle the rest of the values 
    var throttledRest = cooldownWindow
        .SelectMany(o => o.Skip(1))
        .Throttle(dueTime, scheduler);

    return Observable.Merge(firstAfterCooldown, throttledRest);
}
```

This *seems* to work, but I'm having a difficult time reasoning about this, and I get the feeling there are some edge cases here where things might get screwy with duplicate values or something. I'd like to get some feedback from more experienced Rx-ers as to whether or not this code is correct, and/or whether there is a more idiomatic way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here's a test suite (using nuget `Microsoft.Reactive.Testing`):

```
var ts = new TestScheduler();
var source = ts.CreateHotObservable<char>(
    new Recorded<Notification<char>>(200.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext('A')),
    new Recorded<Notification<char>>(300.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext('B')),
    new Recorded<Notification<char>>(500.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext('C')),
    new Recorded<Notification<char>>(510.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext('D')),
    new Recorded<Notification<char>>(550.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext('E')),
    new Recorded<Notification<char>>(610.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext('F')),
    new Recorded<Notification<char>>(760.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext('G'))
);

var target = source.ThrottleSubsequent(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150), ts);
var expectedResults = ts.CreateHotObservable<char>(
    new Recorded<Notification<char>>(200.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext('A')),
    new Recorded<Notification<char>>(450.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext('B')),
    new Recorded<Notification<char>>(500.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext('C')),
    new Recorded<Notification<char>>(910.MsTicks(), Notification.CreateOnNext('G'))
);

var observer = ts.CreateObserver<char>();
target.Subscribe(observer);
ts.Start();

ReactiveAssert.AreElementsEqual(expectedResults.Messages, observer.Messages);
```

and using

```
public static class TestingHelpers
{
    public static long MsTicks(this int i)
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(i).Ticks;
    }
}
```

Seems to pass. If you wanted to reduce it, you could turn it into this:

```
public static IObservable<TSource> ThrottleSubsequent2<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, TimeSpan dueTime, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return source.Publish(_source => _source
        .Window(() => _source
            .Select(x => Observable.Interval(dueTime, scheduler))
            .Switch()
        ))
        .Publish(cooldownWindow =>
            Observable.Merge(
                cooldownWindow
                    .SelectMany(o => o.Take(1)),
                cooldownWindow
                    .SelectMany(o => o.Skip(1))
                    .Throttle(dueTime, scheduler)
            )
        );
}
```

---

**EDIT**:

`Publish` forces sharing of a subscription. If you have a bad (or expensive) source observable with subscription side-effects, `Publish` makes sure you only subscribe once. Here's an example where `Publish` helps:

```
void Main()
{
    var source = UglyRange(10);
    var target = source
        .SelectMany(i => Observable.Return(i).Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10 * i)))
        .ThrottleSubsequent2(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(70), Scheduler.Default) //Works with ThrottleSubsequent2, fails with ThrottleSubsequent
        .Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
}
static int counter = 0;
public IObservable<int> UglyRange(int limit)
{
    var uglySource = Observable.Create<int>(o =>
    {
        if (counter++ == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ugly observable should only be created once.");
            Enumerable.Range(1, limit).ToList().ForEach(i => o.OnNext(i));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Ugly observable should only be created once. This is the {counter}th time created.");
            o.OnError(new Exception($"observable invoked {counter} times."));
        }
        return Disposable.Empty;
    });
    return uglySource;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the testing framework, that looks quite useful. In ThrottleSubsequent2, what are the calls to Publish() doing? Does yours function differently to mine in any material way?

Comment: Added an example with subscription side-effects to show benefits of publish.

Comment: Makes sense. Is it fair to say that you should always use something like Publish() when you don't know whether your transformation will be used with hot or cold Observables?

Comment: If you have a double subscription, generally yes.