# Throttling per selector and picking value immediately if there's been silence

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I came across [Custom Rx operator for throttling only when there's a been a recent value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587529/custom-rx-operator-for-throttling-only-when-theres-a-been-a-recent-value) in SO and though about transforming this a version that can first group queries and then throttle each window. I have one version that almost does it, but it takes the first event in the window, not the last. Then if in the version listed further I switch `First(1)` to `TakeLast(1)`, the first event will be awaited too by the time period. Any advice how to handle this? I tried to fix the code so it's easier to switch between the versions if it matters for this question.

This feels like a surprivisely trick problem. For instance (for the sake of "easiness" of fiddling):

```
public static class RxExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the last element within a group of events as defined by <paramref name="groupSelector"/> and throttled by <paramref name="samplingSelector"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the elements.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TGroupId">The type of the ID to be used in grouping.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="events">The stream of events to be grouped, throttled and selected from.</param>
    /// <param name="groupSelector">The selector function to the group.</param>
    /// <param name="samplingSelector">The selector function for throttle times.</param>
    /// <param name="scheduler">The scheduler to use.</param>
    /// <returns>A throttled stream of events.</returns>
    /// <remarks>HUOM! Tämä on myös Ohjaustyökalun RxExtensions-luokassa.</remarks>
    public static IObservable<T> TakeLastInWindow<T, TGroupId>(this IObservable<T> events, Func<T, TGroupId> groupSelector, Func<TimeSpan> samplingSelector, IScheduler scheduler = null)
    {
        if(events == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(events));
        }

        if(groupSelector == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(groupSelector));
        }


        if(samplingSelector == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(samplingSelector));
        }

        return events.GroupByUntil(groupSelector, grp => grp.Sample(samplingSelector(), scheduler ?? Scheduler.Default)).SelectMany(grp => grp.Take(1));

        /*
        return events
            .GroupBy(groupSelector)
            .SelectMany(grp =>
                grp.Publish(source => source.Window(() => source.Select(x => Observable.Interval(samplingSelector(), scheduler)).Switch())
                .Publish(throttleWindow => Observable.Merge(throttleWindow.SelectMany(o => o.Take(1)), throttleWindow.SelectMany(o => o.Skip(1)).Throttle(samplingSelector(), scheduler)))));
         */
    }
}

internal sealed class Event: IEquatable<Event>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Jäljitystä helpottava tunnus testauksessa.
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Jäljitystä helpottava erätunnus testauksessa.
    /// </summary>
    public int Batch { get; set; }


    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != GetType()) return false;

        return Equals(obj as Event);
    }


    public bool Equals(Event other)
    {
        return other != null && Id == other.Id && Batch == other.Batch;
    }


    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return unchecked(Id.GetHashCode() * 17 + Batch.GetHashCode());
    }
}


public class RxTests
{
    [Test]
    public void TakeLastInWindowTest()
    {
        var sampleInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150);
        var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
        var source = testScheduler.CreateHotObservable(
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200).Ticks, new Event { Id = 0, Batch = 0 }),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200).Ticks, new Event { Id = 0, Batch = 0 }),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200).Ticks, new Event { Id = 0, Batch = 0 }),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200).Ticks, new Event { Id = 0, Batch = 0 }),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300).Ticks, new Event { Id = 1, Batch = 0 }),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300).Ticks, new Event { Id = 1, Batch = 0 }),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500).Ticks, new Event { Id = 2, Batch = 0 }),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500).Ticks, new Event { Id = 2, Batch = 0 }),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(510).Ticks, new Event { Id = 3, Batch = 0 }),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(510).Ticks, new Event { Id = 3, Batch = 0 }),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(550).Ticks, new Event { Id = 4, Batch = 0 }),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(550).Ticks, new Event { Id = 4, Batch = 0 }),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(610).Ticks, new Event { Id = 5, Batch = 0 }),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(610).Ticks, new Event { Id = 5, Batch = 0 }),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(760).Ticks, new Event { Id = 6, Batch = 0 }),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(760).Ticks, new Event { Id = 6, Batch = 0 }));

        var target = source.TakeLastInWindow(key => key.Id, () => sampleInterval, testScheduler);
        var expectedResults = testScheduler.CreateHotObservable(
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200).Ticks, new Event { Id = 0, Batch = 0 }),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(450).Ticks, new Event { Id = 1, Batch = 0 }),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500).Ticks, new Event { Id = 2, Batch = 0 }),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(510).Ticks, new Event { Id = 3, Batch = 0 }),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(550).Ticks, new Event { Id = 4, Batch = 0 }),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(610).Ticks, new Event { Id = 5, Batch = 0 }),
            ReactiveTest.OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(910).Ticks, new Event { Id = 6, Batch = 0 }));

        var observer = testScheduler.CreateObserver<Event>();
        target.Subscribe(observer);
        testScheduler.Start();

        foreach(var xc in observer.Messages)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(xc.Value.Value.Id);
        }

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedResults.Messages, observer.Messages);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking to achieve?